# How to prevent MacOS from sleeping when sound is playing

Tags: audio, sleep-wake, hdmi

I have a mac mini (2020) which is connected to an external (Samsung) TV using HDMI cable.
If video is playing, the mac mini never goes to sleep - as expected, BUT if only sound is playing it does (e.g. when I stream radio from the web).
How do I prevent the mac from going to sleep when only sound is playing? thanks

Comment: Interesting. For at least the past decade I've been running a radio broadcast over a Mac which is unattended all day. The radio keeps it awake. Perhaps it's how the radio presents itself to the browser? https://www.globalplayer.com/live/radiox/london/ if you want to give it a try [idk if it works from outside the UK]

Comment: It works outside of the UK ;)

Comment: @Tetsujin I tried the link and it worked but I suspected its related to the fact that they have a graphic that changes so the video changes and keeps that mac from sleeping. I opened a static tab and sure enough after a while the mac went to sleep. (nice station by the way :) )

Comment: Glad you like it :)) tbh, they used to have a much simpler interface without all the moving graphic. The puter still never slept whilst it was streaming. Conversely, even with the new fancy graphics, if you click the pause on the page, the computer will then sleep after its allotted time. Basically we wake it & start play at breakfast, then leave it until dinner to pause it… it then sleeps until the next day. Been doing the same, across several different Macs, for a decade or more. idk *why* it works, only that it does.

Comment: Hmmm… a late thought - are you *absolutely* certain it's the Mac that sleeps & not the TV? My TV will sleep after a few hours even if I'm watching the damn thing! It has to sense user input every hour or 4, or it thinks you've got bored of it & wandered off. Great when you're watching some 4-hour sports presentation all on the same channel & right near the end it warns you it's about to sleep. Running round finding the remote to waggle at it in the closing moments… grrr ;))

Comment: @Tetsujin, Im basically doing the same as you - start in the morning and pause evening and it also worked for me on my previous Mac. I recently changed to a new Mac-mini and this suddenly started. Im sure its not the TV setting because it shows a "no signal" screen when the mac goes to sleep and only goes to sleep much later.

Comment: I think I've exhausted my know-how on this, sorry. I do wish you luck in your quest. :)

Answer (score 3):

One possible solution is the application [Amphetamine](https://apps.apple.com/us/app/amphetamine/id937984704?mt=12). This app's sole purpose is to prevent the computer from going to sleep when you don't want it too. One of the things it is capable of is conditional sleep prevention. To set this up install the app then in the apps preferences page go the "Triggers" add a new trigger using the "+" button. Name the trigger. Then add the criterion "audio output" using the "+". Then find the HDMI audio output in the drop down box and you're done. (Note: The HDMI audio output might not show up if you are not connected to your TV) Hope this Helps.

Edit: To increase the granularity of the control, you can add multiple condition in the trigger so that all conditions must be met for it to enable. The application trigger will limit it to only if the web browser is open (with a toggle to specify if it needs to be frontmost)(As this isn't perfect you can use another browser to play  the music other than your standard browser to avoid unwanted activation) and if you still want even more granularity you can use CPU utilization as a sort of proxy of the app playing audio. (though this will be inconsistent and would only work if the web browser uses a relatively significant amount of resources while playing music to distinguish it from background activity). Hope these possible workarounds help.

Comment: Or the standard command line utility `caffeinate`.

Comment: @lhf Unfortunately i could not find a `caffeinate` argument that would prevent sleep only if the HDMI (audio or video) is active. The command is kind of a bottom line prevention regardless of the cause and I want a more refined control over when I want it to not go to sleep.

Comment: @jwwolff This looks like it could be exactly what I'm looking for, although it is annoying that there is no "native" way to do this. I'll give it a try.

Comment: Unfortunately Amphetamine does not work for me. The problem with it is that when I added the "HDMI Audio Output" trigger the Mac immediately went into sleep prevention mode regardless of whether there was audio playing or not. In effect this means that the mac will never sleep which is not what I want...